# How to get a list of SCSI-Disks in C/C++ under Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, device, scsi

i need to get a list or any other enumerable class with info about any connected SCSI-disks, with info just like `/proc/scsi/sg/devices`
Please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: What is wrong with just running a awk/perl/python script over /proc/scsi/sg/devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically named a solution in your question -- just open `/proc/scsi/sg/devices` and read from it.

Comment: isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: @skeleten - On Unix, everything is a file.

Comment: There isn't. procfs is the *only* way to get access to a lot of data -- for instance, most of the information displayed by tools like `ps` and `top` is pulled straight out of procfs.